# Unable to install AMDGPU-PRO on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, amd-graphics-card, opencl

I was trying to install amdgpu-pro on ubuntu 20.04 using the official docs. When I ran the following command I get an unmet dependency error.

```bsh
$ sudo ./amdgpu-pro-install -y
deb [ trusted=yes ] file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/ ./
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
Ign:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
Get:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Packages [106 kB]
Get:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease [1,811 B]
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                        
Hit:7 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                                 
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                
Get:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages [1,094 B]              
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]                    
Hit:11 https://cli.github.com/packages focal InRelease                                        
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu focal InRelease                        
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/qucs/qucs/ubuntu focal InRelease                              
Hit:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                              
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ultradvorka/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                        
Hit:16 https://repo.fortinet.com/repo/6.4/ubuntu /bionic InRelease
Fetched 103 kB in 2s (47.5 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '20.20-1098277' (localhost [all]) for 'amdgpu-pro-pin'
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  intel-microcode iucode-tool linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 thermald
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  amdgpu-pro-pin
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/6,004 B of archives.
After this operation, 32.8 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-pro-pin 20.20-1098277 [6,004 B]
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-pro-pin.
(Reading database ... 373803 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../amdgpu-pro-pin_20.20-1098277_all.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-pro-pin (20.20-1098277) ...
Setting up amdgpu-pro-pin (20.20-1098277) ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  intel-microcode iucode-tool linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 thermald
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  amdgpu-pin
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,684 B of archives.
After this operation, 25.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-pin 20.20-1098277 [2,684 B]
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-pin.
(Reading database ... 373816 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../amdgpu-pin_20.20-1098277_all.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-pin (20.20-1098277) ...
Setting up amdgpu-pin (20.20-1098277) ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amdgpu-lib32 : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:2.4.100-1098277)
                Depends: libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 (= 1:2.4.100-1098277)
                Depends: libllvm10.0-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:10.0-1098277)
                Depends: libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
                Depends: libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
                Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
                Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
                Depends: libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
                Depends: libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
                Depends: libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
                Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
                Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
                Depends: libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
                Depends: mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
                Depends: mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 (= 1:20.0.5-1098277)
 amdgpu-pro-lib32 : Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx:i386 (= 20.20-1098277)
                    Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-pro:i386 (= 20.20-1098277)
                    Depends: libgles2-amdgpu-pro:i386 (= 20.20-1098277)
                    Depends: libglapi1-amdgpu-pro:i386 (= 20.20-1098277)
                    Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri:i386 (= 20.20-1098277)
 vulkan-amdgpu-pro:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 (>= 3.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 4.8) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libwayland-client0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried many solutions available online like, fixing broken packages, removing the amd source repository etc. But nothing seems to work and I am stuck. Please help if there is a solution to this problem.

**Update**:

As it turns out I managed to solve the above problem by downgrading `libc6` as shown in this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1315906/unmet-dependencies-libc6-the-package-system-is-broken.

But after this the installation process almost completed but towards the end I got another error. This is the terminal output

```bsh
$ sudo ./amdgpu-pro-install -y
deb [ trusted=yes ] file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/ ./
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
Ign:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
Get:4 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Packages [114 kB]
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/intel-opencl/intel-opencl/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                  
Hit:7 https://cli.github.com/packages focal InRelease                                         
Hit:8 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                                 
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu focal InRelease                         
Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                       
Hit:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                               
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/qucs/qucs/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]                    
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ultradvorka/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                        
Hit:15 https://repo.fortinet.com/repo/6.4/ubuntu /bionic InRelease              
Hit:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed InRelease
Fetched 101 kB in 3s (37.4 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '20.45-1188099' (localhost [all]) for 'amdgpu-pro-pin'

... Some lines omitted here ...

Extracting templates from packages: 100%  
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-dkms-firmware.
(Reading database ... 442228 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../amdgpu-dkms-firmware_5.6.20.906316-1188099_all.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-dkms-firmware (1:5.6.20.906316-1188099) ...
Setting up amdgpu-dkms-firmware (1:5.6.20.906316-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-dkms.
(Reading database ... 442636 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-amdgpu-dkms_5.6.20.906316-1188099_all.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-dkms (1:5.6.20.906316-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-core.
Preparing to unpack .../1-amdgpu-core_20.45-1188099_all.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-core (20.45-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdrm2-amdgpu:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../2-libdrm2-amdgpu_2.4.100-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm2-amdgpu:amd64 (1:2.4.100-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdrm-amdgpu-common.
Preparing to unpack .../3-libdrm-amdgpu-common_1.0.0-1188099_all.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu-common (1.0.0-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../4-libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1_2.4.100-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:amd64 (1:2.4.100-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../5-libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1_2.4.100-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:amd64 (1:2.4.100-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libllvm10.0-amdgpu:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../6-libllvm10.0-amdgpu_10.0-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libllvm10.0-amdgpu:amd64 (1:10.0-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../7-mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers_20.1.6-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../8-libglapi-amdgpu-mesa_20.1.6-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up amdgpu-core (20.45-1188099) ...
Setting up libdrm2-amdgpu:amd64 (1:2.4.100-1188099) ...
Setting up libdrm-amdgpu-common (1.0.0-1188099) ...
Setting up libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:amd64 (1:2.4.100-1188099) ...
Setting up libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:amd64 (1:2.4.100-1188099) ...
Setting up libllvm10.0-amdgpu:amd64 (1:10.0-1188099) ...
Setting up mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:amd64.
(Reading database ... 444771 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri_20.1.6-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdrm2-amdgpu:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../1-libdrm2-amdgpu_2.4.100-1188099_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 (1:2.4.100-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../2-libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1_2.4.100-1188099_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 (1:2.4.100-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../3-libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1_2.4.100-1188099_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:i386 (1:2.4.100-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libllvm10.0-amdgpu:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../4-libllvm10.0-amdgpu_10.0-1188099_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libllvm10.0-amdgpu:i386 (1:10.0-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../5-mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers_20.1.6-1188099_i386.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../6-libglapi-amdgpu-mesa_20.1.6-1188099_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 (1:2.4.100-1188099) ...
Setting up libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 (1:2.4.100-1188099) ...
Setting up libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:i386 (1:2.4.100-1188099) ...
Setting up libllvm10.0-amdgpu:i386 (1:10.0-1188099) ...
Setting up mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386.
(Reading database ... 444807 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri_20.1.6-1188099_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxatracker2-amdgpu:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libxatracker2-amdgpu_20.1.6-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxatracker2-amdgpu:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgbm1-amdgpu:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libgbm1-amdgpu_20.1.6-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgbm1-amdgpu:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libegl1-amdgpu-mesa_20.1.6-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers_20.1.6-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libgles1-amdgpu-mesa_20.1.6-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libgles2-amdgpu-mesa_20.1.6-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx_20.1.6-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libosmesa6-amdgpu:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libosmesa6-amdgpu_20.1.6-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libosmesa6-amdgpu:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../09-mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers_20.1.6-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../10-mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers_20.1.6-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu.
Preparing to unpack .../11-xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu_19.1.0-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu (1:19.1.0-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gst-omx-amdgpu.
Preparing to unpack .../12-gst-omx-amdgpu_1.0.0.1-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gst-omx-amdgpu (1.0.0.1-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-lib.
Preparing to unpack .../13-amdgpu-lib_20.45-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-lib (20.45-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu.
Preparing to unpack .../14-amdgpu_20.45-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu (20.45-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../15-libxatracker2-amdgpu_20.1.6-1188099_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgbm1-amdgpu:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../16-libgbm1-amdgpu_20.1.6-1188099_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../17-libegl1-amdgpu-mesa_20.1.6-1188099_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../18-libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers_20.1.6-1188099_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../19-libgles1-amdgpu-mesa_20.1.6-1188099_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../20-libgles2-amdgpu-mesa_20.1.6-1188099_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../21-libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx_20.1.6-1188099_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../22-libosmesa6-amdgpu_20.1.6-1188099_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../23-mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers_20.1.6-1188099_i386.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-lib32.
Preparing to unpack .../24-amdgpu-lib32_20.45-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-lib32 (20.45-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-pro-core.
Preparing to unpack .../25-amdgpu-pro-core_20.45-1188099_all.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-pro-core (20.45-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgl1-amdgpu-pro-appprofiles.
Preparing to unpack .../26-libgl1-amdgpu-pro-appprofiles_20.45-1188099_all.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-amdgpu-pro-appprofiles (20.45-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../27-libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx_20.45-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx:amd64 (20.45-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libegl1-amdgpu-pro:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../28-libegl1-amdgpu-pro_20.45-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libegl1-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (20.45-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgles2-amdgpu-pro:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../29-libgles2-amdgpu-pro_20.45-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgles2-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (20.45-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libglapi1-amdgpu-pro:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../30-libglapi1-amdgpu-pro_20.45-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglapi1-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (20.45-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgl1-amdgpu-pro-ext:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../31-libgl1-amdgpu-pro-ext_20.45-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-amdgpu-pro-ext:amd64 (20.45-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../32-libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri_20.45-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri:amd64 (20.45-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-pro.
Preparing to unpack .../33-amdgpu-pro_20.45-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-pro (20.45-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../34-libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx_20.45-1188099_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx:i386 (20.45-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libegl1-amdgpu-pro:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../35-libegl1-amdgpu-pro_20.45-1188099_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libegl1-amdgpu-pro:i386 (20.45-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgles2-amdgpu-pro:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../36-libgles2-amdgpu-pro_20.45-1188099_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgles2-amdgpu-pro:i386 (20.45-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libglapi1-amdgpu-pro:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../37-libglapi1-amdgpu-pro_20.45-1188099_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libglapi1-amdgpu-pro:i386 (20.45-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri:i386.
Preparing to unpack .../38-libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri_20.45-1188099_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri:i386 (20.45-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package amdgpu-pro-lib32.
Preparing to unpack .../39-amdgpu-pro-lib32_20.45-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-pro-lib32 (20.45-1188099) ...
Selecting previously unselected package vulkan-amdgpu-pro:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../40-vulkan-amdgpu-pro_20.45-1188099_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vulkan-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (20.45-1188099) ...
Setting up libxatracker2-amdgpu:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up libgbm1-amdgpu:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up gst-omx-amdgpu (1.0.0.1-1188099) ...
Setting up libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up amdgpu-dkms (1:5.6.20.906316-1188099) ...
Loading new amdgpu-5.6.20.906316-1188099 DKMS files...
Building for 5.11.0-27-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.11.0-27-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/amdgpu-dkms-firmware.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.11.0-27-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.20.906316-1188099/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
0
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu:
 amdgpu depends on amdgpu-dkms (= 1:5.6.20.906316-1188099); however:
  Package amdgpu-dkms is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu (1:19.1.0-1188099) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previo
us failure.
           Setting up mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up amdgpu-pro-core (20.45-1188099) ...
Setting up libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up vulkan-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (20.45-1188099) ...
Setting up libosmesa6-amdgpu:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu-pro:
 amdgpu-pro depends on amdgpu (= 20.45-1188099); however:
  Package amdgpu is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-pro (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previo
us failure.
           dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu-pro-lib32:
 amdgpu-pro-lib32 depends on amdgpu (= 20.45-1188099) | amdgpu-hwe (= 20.45-1188099); however:
  Package amdgpu is not configured yet.
  Package amdgpu-hwe is not installed.
 amdgpu-pro-lib32 depends on amdgpu-pro (= 20.45-1188099) | amdgpu-pro-hwe (= 20.45-1188099); h
owever:
  Package amdgpu-pro is not configured yet.
  Package amdgpu-pro-hwe is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-pro-lib32 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libglapi1-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (20.45-1188099) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up libglapi1-amdgpu-pro:i
386 (20.45-1188099) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri:amd64 (20.45-1188099) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri:i386 (20.45-1188099) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-pro-appprofiles (20.45-1188099) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (20.45-1188099) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-pro:i386 (20.45-1188099) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:amd64 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (1:20.1.6-1188099) ...
Setting up libgles2-amdgpu-pro:amd64 (20.45-1188099) ...
Setting up libgles2-amdgpu-pro:i386 (20.45-1188099) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx:amd64 (20.45-1188099) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx:i386 (20.45-1188099) ...
Setting up libgl1-amdgpu-pro-ext:amd64 (20.45-1188099) ...
Setting up amdgpu-lib (20.45-1188099) ...
Setting up amdgpu-lib32 (20.45-1188099) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
 amdgpu
 amdgpu-pro
 amdgpu-pro-lib32
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Again I tried many solutions to no avail please point out any solutions.